# Merge Multiple Shareoint lists and restrict view based on the role

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, view

I am working on 2 types of SharePoint lists for software products.
Business List: This is specific to business and budget-related information + PLM and stakeholders. There are multiple lists, and each represents one business area.
Technical List: This is specific to the technical team + PLM and stakeholders. This is a single list for all business areas.

The PLM and Stakeholder information is overlapping information in both lists. Rather than maintaining this information in multiple lists, I plan to create one list and restrict the view based on the users' roles. E.g. a developer won't see budget information for the project. and a Product Owner won't see the technical details.

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: Does the data need to be secured, or just partitioned for convenience? In other words, if a developer is able to access budget information via a link, will that be a problem?

Comment: I prefer security over partitioning.  However, I am open to any option.

Answer (score 0):

If you have data overlapping multiple lists it sounds like your lists are poorly architected, but that's a question for another time I guess.

Create a "role" column on the destination list. Make it multi-valued if you need to. Add the correct role to each list item as it's migrated to the destination list. Create a filtered view for each role. For example, `WHERE role = 'Technical'`

Note, this is not a security based solution. It's possible to secure each item as it's being migrated, but that solution will lead to problems down the road and I would recommend against it.